# Power of elements in list

Tags: python-3.x, modulo, pow

i have this example code:

```
n = 11698030645065745910098695770921
e = 9569991810443215702618212520777
d = 7874909554574080825236064017913
m = 104228568138
m = int(m)
e = int(e)
n = int(n)
def preparation(m, n):
    block_lenght= len(str(n)) - 1
    m = [str(m)[i:i+block_lenght] for i in range(0, len(str(m)), block_lenght)]
    return m

def encrypt(m, n, e):
    m = preparation(m, n)

    power = [int(i) ** e for i in m]

    modulo = [i%n for i in power]

    total_sum = sum(modulo)

    return total_sum

m = encrypt(m, n, e)
print("m = ", m)
```

Can you tell me why is this algorithm so slow for that big numbers? How can I make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a list `power` by using the in-built [pow](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/pow) function or using `**` operator. See below for both implementations:

```
In [1777]: n = 43787
      ...: e = 31
In [1778]: a
Out[1778]: ['1112', '2222', '3323', '4']

In [1781]: power = [pow(int(i),e) for i in a]
```

OR

```
In [1786]: power = [int(i) ** e for i in a]
```

Then, create another list `modulo` on each element of above created power list:

```
In [1784]: modulo = [i%n for i in power]

In [1785]: modulo
Out[1785]: [19378L, 27732L, 26928L, 30208]
```

Have created another function to calculate `power`. Try and check if the performance increases with this:

```
MOD = 1000000007
def fast_power(base, power):
    result = 1
    while power > 0:
        # If power is odd
        if power % 2 == 1:
            result = (result * base) % MOD

        # Divide the power by 2
        power = power / 2
        # Multiply base to itself
        base = (base * base) % MOD
```

Comment: So I implement your code to mine and it works well for small numbers, but now when I have got this big numbers the algorithm is so slow. Any advice? My old question is now replaced with new one.

Comment: Have introduced another function to calculate `power`. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I have error "name 'MOD' is not defined" so i need to set something as MOD

Comment: Sorry, `MOD = 1000000007`.

Comment: `def fast_power(base, power):
    MOD = 1000000007
    result = 1
    while power > 0:
        # If power is odd
        if power % 2 == 1:
            result = (result * base) % MOD

        # Divide the power by 2
        power = power / 2
        # Multiply base to itself
        base = (base * base) % MOD
    return result

k = fast_power(m, e)
`

Comment: I have got result 632351872, i think its not right number

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be to use apply map with lambda.

> http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

```
a_to_power_e = list(map(lambda x : int(x)**e, a))

a_modulo_n = list(map(lambda x : int(x)%n, a_to_power_e))
```

if you want to reuse the same function more than once, you can do below.

```
cust_power_func = lambda x : int(x)**e
cust_modulo_func = lambda x : int(x)%n
a_to_power_e = list(map(cust_power_func, a))

a_modulo_n = list(map(cust_modulo_func, a_to_power_e))
```